# How to remove the next/previous tabs after the jQuery dataTable initialized from jSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

A jQuery table is initialized from jSON

I know that it will be only one row, so I do not need to show the next/previous tabs after the table.  Nevertheless they are displayed.

Is there any way of removing them?
The code for the table:

```
 table = $("#retrievedTable").dataTable({
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "/cm/credit/getretrievedTable.json", 
    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "orderNumber", "value": $( "#orderNumberInput" ).val() } );
     },
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "bInfo" : false,
    "bRetrieve" : true,
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 20,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
            return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
        },
        "aTargets": [ 0 ],
     "bPaginate": false
    }]
});
```

Comment: By next/previous tabs, do you mean the pagination?

Comment: Pagination does not work at all - I removed  "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",.  Still the tabs next/previous are on the page, adding bPaginate:false did not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only answer I can come up with is to hide it instead of removing it. You can do this by adding this to your css:

```
.dataTables_paginate {
    display: none;
}
```

I've tried it with the example on the [website](https://datatables.net). The css class was found on [this page](https://datatables.net/styling/ids_classes).